# Custom memory layer for A3C

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to create an A3C to play a game using frames as an input.
I think my A3C could benefit from having a form of memory layer like a lstm layer.
From what I understand of how the lstm works, you have to give it data by batch and the memory is only going to work on what's given in the batch.

Unfortunately, it's not possible for me to give the whole replay in the batch as the batch size would be way too big. So I wanted to know if it was possible to create a memory layer that would similar to how a lstm layer works. What I had in mind would generate some values based on the output of a layer from the neural network and decide if it's worth saving the values or keep the previous ones and then this memory layer would be fed to the next layer of the neural network.

```
S = Input(shape = (self.IMAGE_ROWS, self.IMAGE_COLS, self.IMAGE_CHANNELS, ), name = 'Input')
h0 = Convolution2D(1, kernel_size = (8,8), strides = (4,4), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', bias_initializer = 'random_uniform')(S)
h1 = Convolution2D(1, kernel_size = (4,4), strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', bias_initializer = 'random_uniform')(h0)
h2 = Flatten()(h1)
h3 = Dense(256, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', bias_initializer = 'random_uniform') (h2)
h3 = Dropout(0.5)(h3)

# I was thinking of adding the memory layer here 
# It would take the values of h3 and the output would feed h4_k with the values of h3

h4_k = Dense(256, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', bias_initializer = 'random_uniform') (h3)
h4_k = Dropout(0.5)(h4_k)

h5_k = Dense(256, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', bias_initializer = 'random_uniform') (h4_k)
h5_k = Dropout(0.5)(h5_k)
probs_k = Dense(self.n_actions_k, activation = 'softmax')(h5_k)
values_k = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(h5_k)
```

Does this kind of layer already exist? If not how can I create a custom layer in tensorflow with the capacity to choose if it should update it's values or not?

Comment: You can add a custom layer using `tf.keras.layers.Layer`

Comment: Great I'll check it out!